# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /esacp/profile/ User has no profile in Django

Tags: python, django, django-users, django-profiles

So I have almost completed my Django app. But whenever I create the new user, his/her profile is not created automatically and when I open the profile after logging in, I get this error `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /esacp/profile/ User has no profile`

My signals.py is below:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

My views.py of `register()` and `profile()` are below:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your Student Account has been created! You can log in ESACP now.')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
            request.FILES,
            instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your Profile information has been updated.')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
```

My forms.py is below:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

and my apps.py is below:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

Everything to me seems to be fine, anyone knows what's wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Why are you using two signals for creating a profile?

Comment: One is for creating and other is for saving.

Comment: @Khubaib Khawar, `Profile.objects.create` internally call `save` method, so one signal handler is enough

Comment: @minglyu thank you for telling that. I will check by removing the save method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your receivers are not working 
Check if you have,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    users.apps.UsersConfig
]
```

if UsersConfig is not there, it will not be initialized and ready wont be executed, resulting in not importing your receivers

or you can add in **init**.py inside users app

```
default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'
```

To ensure receiver works, just add print("I'm working") inside receivers functions and watch the console

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: thank you so much mate, you cured my headache. It worked after I added `default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'` in `__init__`.py of the users app.